# Why numbering in format fails?

Tags: python, exception, tuples

I have an `IndexError` as follows:

```
print ("Page {1} not found, {2}: {3}".format(page, sys.exc_info()[0], err))

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

My code is:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
        try:       
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "summaries")))
        except (TimeoutException, ConnectionRefusedError) as err:#not a TimeoutError, not the basic set of exceptions

            print ("Page {1} not found, {2}: {3}".format(page, sys.exc_info()[0], err))
            file.write("Page {} not found, {}: {}".format(page, sys.exc_info()[0], err))
            #file.write(str(summary))
            continue#next
```

I solved it with:

```
print ("Page {} not found, {}: {}".format(page, sys.exc_info()[0], err))
```

But I don't understand why I got `IndexError` in the first place, since {3} exists?

Does this mean that `sys.exc_info()[0]` is a tuple?
Why when I print `(type(sys.exc_info()[0])`, the value returned is `<class 'type'>`? Because `exc_info[0]` is made to return the type of error?

Comment: Indices start with 0, not 1.

Comment: You should use `"Page {0}...{1}...{2}"` instead of `"Page {1} ... {2} ... {3}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like it's been mentioned in the comments and as you index with lists, indexing always starts from 0:

```
print ("Page {0} not found, {1}: {2}".format(page, sys.exc_info()[0], err))
```

Comment: Wow, sorry, Indeed! It was so obvious that I could not see it. Thanks!